# react-native attempting to resolve built-in fetch function

Tags: node.js, facebook, reactjs, react-native

I'm attempting to use the `fetch` function in react-native to grab a piece of data from the web. from what I understand reading the docs, the `fetch` function is [built in to react-native.](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html)

when doing so, I get the module resolution error in the attached screenshot, where for whatever reason the react-native bundler is attempting to use the `fetch` provided by typescript from my `~/.cache` directory.

I've previously had typescript 2.6 installed globally via npm, I uninstalled it to see if that might fix things, but the error persists.

I should note that the only things I've done for this project are to create it with create-react-native-app, add a little snippet to the App.js component stolen from the react docs to `fetch` some JSON, and `yarn run eject` the project (this error persisted before and after the ejection)

[image: error image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well in my turkey-induced frenzy, it appears I hadn't properly uninstalled the global typescript install on my computer.

having done so properly, the issue is resolved;

however the issue of react-native's module resolution strategy being incompatible with a global typescript installation persists.